# What is the word for 4 points being co-dimensional?

Tags: soft-question

I know the word isn't co-dimensional, because duh, but like the equivalent of 3 points being co-planer, 2 points being co-linear, and 1 point being co-pointial I guess. But what would the comparison be for 4 points, 5, 6 etc?

Comment: I would guess at "co-spatial" for $3,4,5\dots$ dimensions of "space".  Is there a use you are planning for such a term?

Comment: no not really. I was just thinking about it and I couldn't come up with a term for it. really just for my personal sake.